# Непонятное поведение api.openweathermap.org

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, openweathermap

Всем привет.
Написал простенький код для телеграм бота:

```
            let weather = require('./modules/weather');
bot.on('message', (msg) => {

let command = msg.text.toString().toLowerCase();

if (command && command.indexOf('погода') !== -1) {
    let arr = command.split(/\s/);
    weather(msg, arr[1]);
    return;
}
if (command && command === '/start') return;
bot.sendMessage(chatId, `Неверная команда`);
});  
module.exports = (msg, resp) => {
let chatId = msg.chat.id;
let city = resp.toString().toLowerCase();
let url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?
q=${city}&lang=ru&units=metric&appid=${key}`;
let icons = null;
console.log(url);
request(url, (error, response, body) => {
    let data = JSON.parse(body);

    if(data.cod === '404') return bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Нет такого 
города');
    icons = 
`http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${data.weather[0].icon}.png`;
    bot.sendPhoto(chatId, icons);
    bot.sendMessage(chatId, `В ${data.name} сейчас ${data.main.temp} 
градусов цельсия, влажность воздуха ${data.main.humidity}%, скорость 
   ветра ${data.wind.speed} м/с.`);

});
   };
```

один и тот же запрос из телеграма и браузера возвращает абсолютно разные вещи, хотя ссылки верные. Если точнее - запрашиваю Погоду Москвы, возвращает какой то финский городок. При том что я подставляю название города на кириллице. Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно api использует некую эвристику для вычисления правильного города в случае когда есть неоднозначность, возможно, используя ip адрес клиента.

Сами они рекомендуют запрашивать погоду по id города и предоставляют справочник: http://bulk.openweathermap.org/sample/

Либо можно уточнить запрос, добавив через запятую код страны по ISO 3166 (для России - ru)

```
api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Moscow,ru
```